# Eclipse Python Ubuntu 20.02

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, encoding, pydev

when starting eclipse and starting my pydev project, I get this message:

- Could not find platform independent libraries
- Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
- Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to [:<exec_prefix>]
- Fatal Python error:Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Can somebody help, is this related to my recent ubuntu update?

Best regards
HA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your interpreter configuration is wrong.

-- this could be due to an OS update if you're using the OS interpreter for development (usually I recommend using miniconda: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html to setup a separate environment and using it instead of the OS interpreter).

So, to fix you can try to remove the existing interpreter from the interpreter list and add a new interpreter -- even if at the same location (in `Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python interpreter`).